# Gephi 0.9.1 does not open my GDF files

Tags: java, gephi

**Hello everybody!** 
I wrote a custom javafx program to create network data in form of .gdf-files. They look like this:

`nodedef> name VARCHAR,label VARCHAR,eor FLOAT
43,ACHE,2
47,ACLY,2
590,BCHE,2
...
-4948,hsa-miR-885-3p,2
-4918,hsa-miR-892b,2
-4970,hsa-miR-920,2
-4972,hsa-miR-922,2
...
edgedef> node1 VARCHAR,node2 VARCHAR,weight FLOAT
-6765,1137,5
-6765,1142,5
-3880,1136,5
-3880,1128,5
-3880,8973,5
...`

The whole file: [GDF File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vsrfu0mpmctcla/27-ACHE-BCHE-CHAT-ACLY-SLC18A3-SLC5A7-CHRNA1-CHRNA10-CHRNA2-CHRNA3-CHRNA4-CHRNA5-CHRNA6-CHRNA7-CHRNA9-CHRNB1-CHRNB2-CHRNB3-CHRNB4-CHRND-CHRNE-CHRNG-CHRM1-CHRM2-CHRM3-CHRM4-CHRM5.gdf?dl=0)

My 0.8.2 version of the standalone gephi software has no problem opening those files, they are strictly adherent to the GDF format rules. I even tried a GDF-example-file.

Now, when I try opening them in my (otherwise working) 0.9.1 version, nothing happens at all. I have tried switching JDK versions, but that got me nowhere. File name length also has no influence on the problem.

If anybody has an idea as to what could be the problem, I would greatly appreciate any hints!

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using?

Comment: Yes, of course! I included it in the original post.

Comment: Sounds like a bug after all would it be an option to open an issue in GitHub?